# Remove float numbering in lof and lot, but ONLY there

Tags: floats, captions, numbering

I am in a situation of having usual tables and figures that receive a number each through use of `\caption`. Because my article has to conform to APA style rules, which are basically opposite to anything one would like to see in an article layout, but especially contrary to anything LaTeX does automatically, I have to reset float numbers frequently within the text, making lof and lot look really awkward.

Is there a way to remove float numbers from lof and lot, leaving the entries only with their short captions, but NOT use `\caption*` in order to keep the numbers and references within the text? Or is my only chance to achieve this via `\caption*` and `\addcontentsline` in each float individually (hope you catch me disliking this idea)?

Comment: Can you show a short TeX code resulting in your issue? Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: When you say that the float numbers should reset, what do you mean?  Some quick searching only turned up that APA wants them numbered consecutively, with nothing about reseting.  Are you wanting to reset the counter with each section?  Would numbering them sec.fig be acceptable (eg, Figure 3.2)?  Would it work to have "Figures in Section 3" in the lof?  I agree that reseting the numbers is the opposite of anything one would like to see in an article.  I don't agree that that is your only option.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single code snippet causing a problem or a minimal working example reproducing an issue, this is a conceptual pita. So I was looking for a config switch that I did not find documented. Appreciated your take-a-step-back-and-think approach though, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `tocloft` package has no specific macros for this. However, the title/figure/table numbers are typeset by the `\numberline` macro. Changing this will change the Toc/Lof/Lot outputs, but be careful where you change it.

The following gives chapter/section etc numbers in the ToC bu no figure or table numbers in the Lof/Lots.

```
% tocloftprob.tex  Getting Tocs, Lofs and Lot samples

\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\let\oldnumberline\numberline % save original definition of \numberline
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{} % ignore any numbers
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\let\numberline\oldnumberline % restore original definition

\chapter{One}
\section{Initial}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}
\section{Initial}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just put the redefinition inside a group.

Comment: Beautiful short solution. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I could have used a group but wanted to show another way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside your `.lot` or `.lof` file you will see entries that look like this:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3}Picture of a tiger}{2}
```

Getting rid of that number is simply a number of changing the definition of `\numberline` within the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` commands.

Something like the following should work:

```
\NewCommandCopy{\originallistoffigures}{\listoffigures} % ❶
\RenewDocumentCommand{\listoffigures}{} % ❷
   {{ % ❸
      \RenewDocumentCommand{\numberline}{m}{} % ❷ ❹
      \originallistoffigures
   }}
```

We start by saving the definition of `listoffigures` ❶.

I'm doing what I can to push people to use `\NewDocumentCommand` et al. in place of `\newcommand` et al., If you're using an old version of LaTeX without `xparse` in the kernel, you'll need to load `\usepackage{xparse}` or rewrite the `\RenewDocumentCommand` instances ❷ to use `\renewcommand*`.

We enclose the definition in an extra set of braces ❸ so that the redefinition won't impact anything we don't want it to (e.g., if you have your table of contents after the list of figures). Then we redefine `\numberline` ❹ to take its argument and discard it.

Why do I not have my `%`s immediately after each line? Well at ❶, this should be in the preamble and the space doesn't matter. At ❷ any spaces will be ignored as `\RenewDocumentCommand` looks for its third argument. And at ❸ and ❹, `\originallistoffigures` will be going into vertical mode when it prints the **List of Figures** heading at the top of the list of figures, so all the spaces surrounding it will be ignored as well.

Comment: Also, be careful with your use of commenting. Adding a space after a command definition and then your comment `%` leaves that space in the input stream. See [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/1qMqLSQC) (that matches your setup) that produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOmvp.png). In your case it doesn't present a problem because you're setting a sectional unit (chapter/section, which does some legwork to set things up properly), but in horizontal mode it would introduce an spurious space.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of the dangers and also of the lack thereof in this instance. Since a list of figures will happen instantiate vertical mode, any spaces in the definition around `\originallistoffigures` will be discarded. If anything, the misleading thing is the `%` immediately after `{{` at ❸

Comment: ...so then leave it in? Why? Why not just provide something that educates users in a more global context?