# Remove indentation in list of figures when using caption package

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I am typesetting a book, and I don’t want to have figure numbers in my captions; thus I am using `labelformat=empty` in the captions package. Similarly, I want to suppress numbers in my list of figures, so my preamble looks like this:

`\usepackage[listformat=empty,labelformat=empty,]{caption}`

Let’s assume this image in my text:

```tex
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption[\textit{Title of the Work, which can also be a bit longer}, \textsc{Author of the work}, 2010, No Copyright]{Title of the work} \label{fig:some-label}
\end{figure}
```

When I print my `\listoffigures` I get an indentation. Is there any way to get rid of this?

### [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/7121769155vpjmrtzcnkds) (this is an edit link, feel free to play around):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[belowskip=-11pt,listformat=empty,labelsep=none,labelformat=empty]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption[\textit{Title of the Work, which can also be a bit longer}, \textsc{Author of the work}, 2010, No Copyright]{Title of the work} \label{fig:some-label}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sorry you are right. I added a link

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612537/remove-float-numbering-in-lof-and-lot-but-only-there.  Actually, the indentation is in `\l@figure`.

Comment: Sorry, this is nothing in this with `\l@figure`, what does it mean the indentation is in `\l@figure` — how do I get rid of it?

Comment: don't put the example in a external  link. Such links will be dead at some time. Add it to your question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are absolutely right. Sorry for that, and thanks for modifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186844/56823, here is the solution:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[belowskip=-11pt,listformat=empty,labelformat=empty]{caption}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{0em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption[\textit{Title of the Work, which can also be a bit longer}, \textsc{Author of the work}, 2010, No Copyright]{Title of the work} \label{fig:some-label}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s it! Thank you so much. Is there any way to get a hanging indentation (first line no indented, following lines indented)? I know that this is a different question  ...

Comment: Likely, but this is way harder since normally what you can control is the indentation w.r.t. the “Figure 1” label, which is a separated object. Here you want to indent two lines that are stored together, so it requires patching the code displaying them more deeply, and I haven’t found a simple way even using `tocloft`. As you said, you should ask this in a new question.